# How to implement Graph-API to get data of Facebook Workplace

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented Facebook API in our APP by using Graph-API. Now I am trying to implement FB-workplace in my application, but i am not able to get any workplace details by using graph-API. I am having my access_token.
I am using FB Graph-API explorer and Postman, but from both the ways i am getting nothing/Error. So What would i change in this to get that data or any more permission needs to update. 
Please help in this.

{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AjRPf0Xnp7tkluvI9kWo"
    }
}

[image]

Comment: What kind of token are you using? Are you a system administrator for that Workplace community?

Comment: I have created a workplace Group in my **FB-workplace application**. In FB-Developers tool(**Graph API Explorer**) i am trying to access that but not getting any data regarding my workplace account details, even my normal FB account and FB-workplace login details are same. I am getting only my normal FB account details not the workplace.